# Does autocomplete=off work well with bootstrap as well?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, radio-button

HTML code:

```
 <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2 gallery-item">
                <div style="padding-top: 50%; float:right;">
                    <label class="btn btn-info" for="notASign">
                        <input type="radio" name="radio-button-group" id="radioid" autocomplete="off" >Radiobuttontext
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Does not really work for me on page refresh. The radiobutton remains selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Radio buttons are normally intended for selecting a single item from a group. Because your radio button is only one in a group of one, it's selected by default. It might make more sense to use a checkbox here:

```
<div class="checkbox">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox"> Check me out
  </label>
</div>
```

It won't be checked by default. Additionally `autocomplete=off` is intended for use in form fields, and disables the browser from remembering what a user has entered previously. It won't affect radio buttons or checkboxes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion